# getting error cannot apply operator to operands of type system.datetime and string

Tags: c#, linq, date, datetime

I am using Linq query but getting error
`Cannot apply operator >= to operands of type system.datetime and string`

here is my linq query

```
 var myBirthDate= BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");

 var myList= (from myEntity in myEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                                 where
                                     myEntity.id== Id &&
                                     myEntity.birthdate >= myBirthDate
                                 select myEntity).Take(1);
```

I convert date to to  `yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss` format because i get in other format from client.

How can i avoid this error?

Comment: Exception message is self descriptive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will result to a string after using the `ToString()` method and not a Datetime

```
var myBirthDate= BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
```

Use [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a DateTime from the value provided by your client. Then use it in your query.

Answer (score 1):

If the date you receive is different from the current culture you can use DateTime.Parse to convert to a correct DateTime variable.

As you are using ToString to convert a DateTime type to a formatted date string, your myBirthDate variable will become a String, thus the >= won't work as expected.

Here is a sample:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] dateStrings = {"2008-05-01T07:34:42-5:00", 
                              "2008-05-01 7:34:42Z", 
                              "Thu, 01 May 2008 07:34:42 GMT"};
      foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
      {
         DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
         Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to {1} time {2}", 
                           dateString, 
                           convertedDate.Kind.ToString(), 
                           convertedDate);
      }                              
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how i can fit your answer as per my question. Can you check your answer again please?

Comment: Your problem is clear. The line var myBirthDate= BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss"); generates a String variable, thus you can't compare it using >=. You need to convert it to a DateTime type to be able to compare dates.